# PySpark Fill NAs with values N times After Join

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark

I have two dataframes that look like the following (these are simplified versions of them):

```
df1:
```

[image]

```
df2:
```

[image]

I want to figure out a dynamic way to join them such that the result is

```
df3:
```

[image]

I know one way would be to create two separate dataframes out of df1 filtering out each segment and then unioning them after the join liek the following:

```
df_a = df1.filter(col('segment') == lit('a'))
df_b = df1.filter(col('segment') == lit('b'))

df_a_joined = df_a.join(df2, df_a.key == df2.key, 'full')
df_a_joined = df_a_join.withColumn('segment', coalesce(col('segment'), lit('a'))
df_b_joined = df_a.join(df2, df_b.key == df2.key, 'full')
df_b_joined = df_b_joined.withColumn('segment', coalesce(col('segment'), lit('b'))
df_3 = df_a_join.unionAll(df_b_joined)
```

IN reality though, the segment column I'm dealing with can have an unknown number of values so the above is not the option.  Is there a way to dynamically do this?

Comment: could you elaborate on the logic? why key=3 doesn't appear in the final df?

Comment: ah sorry that's a typo on my part.  key = 3 should appear in final logic.  Let me edit

Answer (score 0):

Modify df2 before join. See the logic and code below

```
new =(df1.join(
     #Introduce column segment in df where you replicate the distinct segments in df1 n times. where n= to the number of rows in df2
    df2.withColumn('segment',explode(split(lit(','.join(df1.select("segment").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())),','))).drop_duplicates()
     , how='outer', on=['segment','key'])
      .orderBy('key'))
        .show()


+-------+---+-----+------+
|segment|key|count|count2|
+-------+---+-----+------+
|      a|  1|    5|     4|
|      b|  1|    3|     4|
|      a|  2|    6|    10|
|      b|  2|    4|    10|
|      a|  3| null|   231|
|      b|  3| null|   231|
|      b|  4| null|     2|
|      a|  4| null|     2|
|      a|  5| null|     3|
|      b|  5| null|     3|
+-------+---+-----+------+
```